# Rails 4 - undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, web

[image]When I try to access the view show the following error occurs: **undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass**

Controller **HomesController**

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @homes = Home.all
    end

    def new
        @home = Home.new
    end

    def create
        @home = Home.new home_params
        if @home.save
            redirect_to @home, notice: 'Registro cadastrado com sucesso.'
        else
            render action: :index
        end
    end

    def show
        @home = Home.find params[:id]
    end

    private

        def home_params
            params.require(:home).permit(:name, :ip_servidor)
        end

end
```

View **show.html.erb:**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h2>Imóvel: <%= @home.name %></h2>
<h2>Ip do Servidor: <%= @home.ip_servidor %></h2>

<%= link_to "Editar", edit_home_path(@home) %>
```

Comment: seems `@home` is nil, so your controller action is not getting run. Are you sure that is the exact code, eg. your show action isn't under the `private` line?

Comment: show the params which are passed.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Was using the SQLite3 database,then switched to postgresql and it worked.

file **database.yml**:

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

**Before**:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3
```

**After**:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  encoding: unicode
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  database: webapi_development
```